# What is the best "how to" site to learn how to program for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

What is the best "how to" site to learn how to program for iPhone?

Comment: May want to consider making this a community wiki.

Answer (score 5):

[The iPhone Developer Connection](https://developer.apple.com/ios/) by Apple themselves. On the site you will find.

- Reference Documents outlining the
  various technologies.
- Tutorials and Getting Started Guides for each type
  of thing to do with the iPhone
- Sample
  Code that shows off the power of the
  SDK
- Registered developers get
  access to Videos showing everything
  from installing the SDK to
  publishing.

Also check out [this iTunes U course](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-programming-spring-2009/id384233222) (iTunes link) put out by Stanford that covers a look to good tips and items on iPhone Programming

Here is the [course homepage](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) at Stanford for the above course.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Apple's sample code library. A lot of the code isn't exactly perfect -- some of it is still using 2.x idioms -- but the library itself is quite extensive.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice compilation here on SO:
[What are the best Cocoa-Touch/iPhone programming blogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232570/what-are-the-best-cocoa-touch-iphone-programming-blogs)

Here is a well written article on "Cocoa is my girlfriend" that describes how to create a small iPhone app from scratch:
[Cocoa Touch Tutorial: iPhone Application Example](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/10/01/cocoa-touch-tutorial-iphone-application-example/)

A good beginners article to learn Objective-C is Scott Stevensons ["Learn Objective-C"](http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/).
(As it was written in the pre-iPhone era, it targets Mac software developers, but it is about basic language concepts - so it valid for both platforms)

Answer (score 1):

The official [iPhone developer portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/) has all the docs and some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I had started out looking at this site: http://www.appsamuck.com/  Its been a while, not sure if they've updated it but about back in Feb 2009 it was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience (I wasn't initially familiar with Objective-C or even C, for that matter - my programming background was PHP Javascript, and shell scripting), I found a number of books more helpful than any website - maybe this is the answer you're looking for:

- "Programming in Objective-C 2.0" by Stephen Kochan (for learning the language. Until I had this book, I continued to be confused with most of Objective-C)
- "iPhone SKD" published by O'Reilly (for getting an initial grasp of how to do things)
- Developer Documentation (part of Xcode - try [Alt-double clicking] on a word in Xcode)
- google search
- stackoverflow.com
- occasionally even the framework header files (in Xcode) of the libraries you're using

Using the first three tools, I found that I could figure out most of what I needed to know. When I was at a loss after checking those sources and doing a google search, this forum has been indispensable for learning what I need.